# How to approach this question about recursive sequences

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Just practicing some questions about sequences and came across the one below

The sequence $(F_n)$ of Fibonacci numbers is defined by the recursive relation

$F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n\ $   with $F_1=F_2 = 1$

Use the recursive relation for $F_n$ to find a recursive relation for the sequence of ratios

$a_n=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$

I have never seen anything like this before and was just wondering if someone could give me the starting Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the recursive equation by $F_{n+1}$:
$$
\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}=1+\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}
$$
Write that in terms of $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$.

Comment: So would it be $1+\frac{1}{a_n}& @robjohn

Comment: What would be $1+\frac1{a_n}$?

Comment: It in terms of a(n+1) and a(n)

Comment: $1+\frac1{a_n}$ is the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Since $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ then

$a_n = \frac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n}$

From this you should be able to derive an expression for $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Where would I start doing the derivation? and how do I know when I have found the recursive relation to the sequence of ratios